# Create file for download without saving on server with PHP

Tags: php, file, download, save

Say my PHP code was

```
<?php

// Get form variables using POST method
$MarriagePostMortem=stripslashes($_POST['MarriagePostMortem']);
$AutoSavesToKeep=stripslashes($_POST['AutoSavesToKeep']);

// Open and write file
$myFile="S3S.cfg";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w+') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, "The Sims 3 Starter Configuration
-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-
MarriagePostMortem  $MarriagePostMortem
AutoSavesToKeep $AutoSavesToKeep
-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-");
fclose($fh); 

//echo "file written\n";
?>
```

I want to send the file directly to the user for download without saving it to the server. I'm **really** not all that great with PHP, so what exactly would I need to add/change to do so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Heres how you should do it, your html tags should be lower case & stay clear of tables unless your outputting a table of values, use divs with css. You can also post back to the script, as variables received from the form are specific you just check there the right value and then send the data back to the user.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $mpm = (!empty($_POST['mpm']) && ($_POST['mpm']=='true' || $_POST['mpm']=='false'))?$_POST['mpm']:die('Wrong parameter type');
    $astk = (!empty($_POST['astk']) && is_numeric($_POST['astk']))?$_POST['astk']:die('Wrong parameter type');


    $content  = "The Sims 3 Starter Configuration".PHP_EOL;
    $content .= "-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-".PHP_EOL;
    $content .= "MarriagePostMortem  $mpm".PHP_EOL;
    $content .= "AutoSavesToKeep $astk".PHP_EOL;
    $content .= "-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-".PHP_EOL;

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=S3S.cfg');
    header('Content-Length: '.strlen($content));
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    echo $content;
    exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sims 3 Starter Configuration</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Sims 3 Starter Configuration</h1>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="reset" value="Clear changes">
<br />  
<p>marriagepostmortem
  <select name="mpm">
    <option value="true">enabled</option>
    <option value="false" selected="selected">disabled</option>
  </select>
  Keep marriage lines on family tree entries after death. experimental!</p>

<p>autosavestokeep
  <select name="astk">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
  Number of autosaves to keep.</p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Generate"></p>
</form>
<p>Drag the file onto the sims 3 starter to add configurations.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a more correct way to do this than Dagon's answer, and this answer also includes solving the header issue you encountered by reloading the page.

Answer (score 11):

```
header ("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=S3S.cfg");
echo $string; //the string that is the file
```

Comment: I'm now getting the error messages shown here: http://pastehtml.com/view/c0zgndz2d.html

Comment: @Kuuchuu You can't send headers twice.  Check out Lawrence Cherone's answer.