# Save downloaded file in to a folder

Tags: php, file

I am having troubles because I can't save a downloaded file into a folder. The following code is only able to download the file. How should be the code to save it?

```
file_put_contents($file, $data_row, LOCK_EX);

file_put_contents('/var/www/file', $file);

 download($file);

function download($file) {
    if (!headers_sent()) {
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

            if (ob_get_level()) {
                ob_end_clean();
            }

            readfile($file, 'rb');

            exit();
        } else {
            exit('Error: Could not find file ' . $file . '!');
        }
    } else {
        exit('Error: Headers already sent out!');
    }       
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot save a file to a users folder. You have to let the user make that decision for obvious reasons. If this were not the case anyone could store viruses on your system with the greatest of ease

Comment: Hello thank you for answering, I didn't explain it well. I have a script that generates a file and I wan't the script to save the file in to the route var/www.

Comment: You want the generated file to go into the receiving users var/www or you want to store it in var/www on the server there?

Comment: Yes, I want to store it in var/www on the server.

Comment: Do you have to save the file for later use? Otherwise you can generate it and not save it to the file system https://stackoverflow.com/a/10966633/4178487

Comment: Yes, I need to use it later.

Comment: I have finally solved my problem
 $mydir = '/var/www/';
//check route
if (!is_dir($mydir)) {
    $mydir = str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)) . '/';
}